# Clarification regarding rapid publications in journals

Tags: publications, peer-review

I had a query regarding some reputed journals in mathematics that claim rapid publication: in particular, the *New York Journal of Mathematics*. I normally see papers in that journal that have been getting published in around 6-8 months, which, according to me, is the average time for any journal. So can someone clarify as to what they mean by *rapid publication*? Does it mean that papers are accepted in less time than other journals?

Comment: I've seen comments by math folks here that publication might take a year or more, so 6-8 months sounds rapid in that context.

Comment: It is also not unusual for math journals to have delays of 6 months up to a few years between acceptance for publication and "official" publication. These are obviously easily avoidable with a suitable workflow.

Comment: Note that NYJM is online only. Print journals normally take longer, having more steps in the process, though an online version might appear long before it sees print. I'm surprised that you see anything less than a year as average or normal.

Comment: FYI the AMS does surveys of journals' average backlogs/time-to-publish and you'll see that > 1 year is common, even for online publication (though less common for online-only journals): https://www.ams.org/journals/notices/202010/rnoti-p1607.pdf

Answer (score 7):

That journal is all electronic, and has a reputation for finalizing the manuscript and getting it included in an issue quickly.  They just keep adding to the issue until it is time to start the next.

This is less important these days when many journals have "early online" availability prior to inclusion in a journal.  Still, it is nice to be able to quickly point to a volume number and page number when updating your CV.

Some journals still have months or years between when a paper is accepted and when it it even put online.

The journal is not much faster or slower than most for getting a paper accepted, since they deal with the same pool of potential referees as other journals.  But the second step, acceptance to being available in a volume, is about as fast as you will see in mathematics.